# parse user credentials from yaml file into the shell script

Tags: shell, parsing, jenkins, passwords, yaml

I have to parse the user credentials of Bugzilla account from yaml file into the shell script which triggers a Jenkins job.

```html
---
- name: 'USER_BUGZILLA'
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
        name: 'bugzilla_bot'
        key: 'user'

- name: 'PASSWORD_BUGZILLA'
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
        name: 'bugzilla_bot'
        key: 'password'
```

Can anyone pls suggest me on how to solve this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your yaml file is named "foo.yaml"

```
read -r user password <<<$(grep key foo.yaml | sed "s/^.[^']*'//" | sed "s/'.*$//")
```

$user will hold the username
$password will hold the password

Comment: Excellent !!!, after striping this out I need to login to bugzilla using that $user and $password as `bugzilla login` which prompts `Bugzilla username`: $user and `Bugzilla Password`: $password; these values needs to be passed in shell script without user interaction because this script will be run by Jenkins job

Comment: Can't you pass the username and password via --username=USERNAME and --password=PASSWORD? - https://manpages.debian.org/testing/bugzilla-cli/bugzilla.1.en.html

Comment: I tried bugzilla login --username myuser --password mypswd , 
its prompting me this again `bugzilla login --username myuser --password myuser
usage: bugzilla [-h] [--bugzilla BUGZILLA] [--nosslverify] [--cert CERT]
                [--login] [--username USERNAME] [--password PASSWORD]
                [--ensure-logged-in] [--no-cache-credentials]
                [--cookiefile COOKIEFILE] [--tokenfile TOKENFILE] [--verbose]
                [--debug] [--version]
                {new,query,info,modify,attach,login} ...
bugzilla: error: unrecognized arguments: --username --password myuser`

Comment: finally able to login , Thanks

Comment: Cool please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.